# Where can I find the bin/debug folder in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for the bin/debug folder in visual studio 2019 so that I can find the .exe file for my visual studio application. I have looked all over in the solotion explorer. Help please!

Comment: Did you look in the project folder? (in Windows Explorer)

Comment: No, how do 
I find the project folder?

Comment: Right-click on the project and select **"Open Folder in File Explorer"** or maybe this option is in the solution object.

Comment: There is a button on a PC keyboard to the left of the CTRL on the right side that opens up the context menu, same as right click. The button looks like a menu icon (a square with lines inside)

Comment: @JohnAlexiou There used to be that button, unfortunate many "modern" keyboards have that super usefull button replaced by the "FN" button. If you still have such a good keyboard, never loose it, it's so precious ...

Comment: @GuidoG - [Buy one from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01BFCBNEI/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_image?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Answer (score 4):

> I have looked all over in the solotion explorer

The bin folder only shows up in solution explorer if you turn on Show All Files using this button at the top:

[image]

No need to "look all over" by the way; right under it is a search box you can type into..

If you're tying to find the bin folder so you can get your exe and put it somewhere to run it independently of visual studio, consider using the **Publish** option on the Build menu instead

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Open Folder in File Explorer** option under the project and/or solution context menu.

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]